# Computing the dobule integral $\iint_{D} e^{(x+y)^{2}} \, dxdy$ over a region $D$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question.** Evaluate the double integral
>   $$ \iint_{D} e^{(x+y)^{2}} \, dxdy $$
>   over the region $D=\left \{ \left ( x,y \right ):0\leq x-y\leq x+y\leq 1 \right \}$.

I can get the region which is bounded by $x+y=1$, $y=x$, and $x>0$. But I can't figure out how to integrate it. Please help me.

Comment: Hi, I formatted your question so that the title better represents your question. Hope this is to your liking. Also, it is recommended to spare a moment to give a read on the guide: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: And as a hint, perhaps you can begin with the change of variables $(u, v) = (x-y, x+y)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use the substitution $$\begin{cases}u:=x+y\\v:=x-y\end{cases}$$ Then we get $$\iint_D e^{(x+y)^2}~dxdy=\iint_{C} e^{u^2}\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right|~dudv$$ where $C:=\{(u,v):0\leq v\leq u\leq 1\}$ and $$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right|=\det\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}$$
Notice that the new integral is independent of $v$ (determine the bounds on this new integral and this will be very nice!).

Comment: are the bounds, 0<u<1 and 0<v<u? So the answer is -0.5(e-1)?

Comment: That looks pretty good. As a technical note, the bounds are $0\leq u\leq 1$ and $0\leq v\leq u$ (but the difference between $<$ and $\leq$ is nothing in terms of the integral, so this is just a technicality). More importantly: I'm not sure where you get the $-$ sign in your answer, and it should actually be a $\frac{1}{4}$ rather than a $\frac{1}{2}$ since we have the factor $$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|$$which I leave for you to compute.

Comment: I forgot it should be absolute value. Because x=(u+v)/2 and y=(u-v)/2, the Jacobian I got is dxdy = 0.5dudv. thanks for your answer, very helpful.

Comment: That's exactly right! Happy to help.